# JSON dumping a dictionary where some values are PyDantic models

Tags: python, json, dictionary, pydantic

Assume a dictionary with an arbitrary structure, where some values are native Python objects and others are instances of PyDantic's `BaseModel` subclasses

e.g.

```py
my_dict = {"key1": "value1",
           "key2": {"key3": pydantic_object1, 
                    "key4": 4},
           "key5": pydantic_object2}
```

I want to dump this dictionary to a JSON file. The naive solution of using `BaseModel.model_dump()` to convert first all the PyDantic objects to dictionaries and then using `json.dump` doesn't work, because some of the attributes of the PyDantic objects cannot be serialized by the native serializer, e.g. `datetimes`s and other custom objects which their serializers are attached to the object's implementation.

I also couldn't figure out how to write a custom encoder that will user PyDantic's built in JSON encoder.

How would you solve this (PyDantic v2 and above)